# Javascript wont run in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms, session

I have this piece of code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) && $_POST['btnSubmit'])
        {
            require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'database.php');
            $derpCard = $card;
            $derpAccessGroup = $_POST['tbAccessGroup'];
            $derpComments = $_POST['tbComments'];

            if(isset($_POST['cbActivated']))
                $derpActive = $_POST['cbActivated'];
            else
                $derpActive = "DEACTIVATED";

            $x = editCard($derpCard,$derpAccessGroup, $derpComments, $derpActive);
            if($x)
            {
                $_SESSION['editcard'] = $derpCard;
                $_SESSION['editgroup'] = $derpAccessGroup;
                $_SESSION['editcomments'] = $derpComments;
                $_SESSION['editstatus'] = $derpActive;
                            echo "<script>";
                echo "alert(\"Done!\");";
                echo "</script>";
            }
            echo "<script>location.reload(true);</script>";
        }
```

Basically, editCard runs an SQL "UPDATE ... where..." to edit the content within the db. If this is sucessful, I want it to display an alert telling the user it's been updated, as well as refresh the page.

Both the alert and reload code do not run, and i've been trying any and all alternatives! If someone has any idea as to simply refresh the page (thats the minimum i need!) It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't show us PHP and tell us that JavaScript doesn't work. The problem is either that the PHP doesn't generate the JavaScript that you want, or that the JavaScript that you want doesn't do what you think it should. Determine which of those is the case and focus on that part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have to apologize if this answer is too short but the question is too broad or is missing more info. I noticed that one of your lines is wrong.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'database.php');

should be:
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/database.php');
```

There should be / in it since $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns something like this:

"C:/xampp/htdocs"

So if you are to concatenate that with "database.php", you'll be having 
"C:/xampp/htdocsdatabase.php" instead of "C:/xampp/htdocs/database.php"

In any case, you should try using firebug or similar browser add-on to help you debug those javascript errors(if there are any).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try to format the script echo like this:

```
echo "\n<script>\n<!--\n";
echo "alert(\"Done!\");";
echo "\n-->\n</script>\n";
```

and

```
echo "\n<script>\n<!--\nlocation.reload(true);\n-->\n</script>\n";
```

**Note the new lines added.**

Comment: Wrapping the inside of script elements with HTML comments is a technique for preventing Netscape 2 era browsers from treating the script as content to be rendered. There is no reason to do it in 1999 (and it is now 2013).

Comment: That's just a practice. What I stressed was the new lines.

Answer (score -1):

You appear to be missing the type attribute for script.

If you want to specify javascript, you need to include the type.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "alert(\"Done!\")";
echo "</script>";
```

Same goes with the other line

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">location.reload(true);</script>";
```

If the above does not help in the slightest, the problem could be with your logic statements, or that your javascript may just not be outputting what you want.

There are tools to help you figure out these issues, such as the apache logs and firebug plugin

EDIT: Forgot missing semicolon

Comment: The type attribute is optional since HTML 5.

Comment: So it is, I forgot about that sorry. But is that really reason to give me minus reputation? After all he may not be using HTML5.